# Using flexsearch with NextJs to build a search API

Tags: next.js13, flexsearch

I'm trying to build an API for searching using [NextJs](https://nextjs.org/) and [Flexsearch](https://github.com/nextapps-de/flexsearch).

There's an indexer task which scans the whole site and store the index on disk. When the NextJs is started, these files are read to keep a document index in memory. We are exposing an `/api/search` endpoint where we search inside the previous document index.

This is the relevant code for each part, excluding the indexer which is not interesting for now.

This code creates the document index on memory:

```
const documentIndex = new Document({
  tokenize: 'full',
  document: {
    id: 'id',
    index: ['title', 'section', 'content'],
    store: true
  }
});


function buildIndex() {
  const keys = fs
    .readdirSync('search/data/', { withFileTypes: true })
    .filter((item) => !item.isDirectory())
    .map((item) => item.name.split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.'));

  for (let i = 0, key; i < keys.length; i += 1) {
    key = keys[i];
    const data = fs.readFileSync(`search/data/${key}.json`, 'utf8');
    documentIndex.import(key, data ?? null);
  }

  return documentIndex;
}
```

Then the API endpoint is implemented that way:

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
const { serverRuntimeConfig } = getConfig();
import { EnrichedDocumentSearchResultSetUnit } from 'flexsearch';
import getConfig from 'next/config';

const maxContentResultsPerPage = 3;
const maxAgeSeconds = 86400; // 1 day

export interface Section {
  id: number;
  path: string;
  sectionPath: string;
  title: string;
  section: string;
  content: string;
}

export interface Page {
  id: number;
  path: string;
  title: string;
  content: string;
  sections: Section[];
}

function getResults(query: string, fieldNames: string[]) {
  const results = serverRuntimeConfig.documentIndex.search(query, {
    index: fieldNames,
    enrich: true
  }) as EnrichedDocumentSearchResultSetUnit<Section>[];

  return results.pop()?.result.map((value) => {
    return {
      id: value.doc.id,
      title: value.doc.title,
      section: value.doc.section,
      sectionPath: value.doc.sectionPath,
      path: value.doc.path,
      content: value.doc.content
    };
  });
}

const filterSections = (sections: Section[]): Section[] => {
  const visitedSections: Record<string, Section> = {};
  const sectionsOrder: string[] = [];
  const finalSections: Section[] = [];

  sections.forEach((entry) => {
    if (entry.section in visitedSections) {
      if (entry.id < visitedSections[entry.section].id) {
        visitedSections[entry.section] = entry;
      }
    } else {
      visitedSections[entry.section] = entry;
      sectionsOrder.push(entry.section);
    }
  });

  sectionsOrder.forEach((section) => {
    if (finalSections.length < maxContentResultsPerPage) {
      const entry = visitedSections[section];
      finalSections.push(entry);
    }
  });

  return finalSections;
};

const searchHandler = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse): Promise<void> => {
  const titleResults = getResults(req.query.q as string, ['title']);
  const sectionResults = getResults(req.query.q as string, ['section', 'content']);

  const visitedTitles: Record<string, Section> = {};
  const titleOrder: string[] = [];

  const results: Page[] = [];
  const added: number[] = [];

  const pages: Record<string, Page> = {};
  const pageOrder: string[] = [];

  if (titleResults !== undefined) {
    titleResults.forEach((entry) => {
      if (visitedTitles[entry.title] !== undefined) {
        if (entry.id < visitedTitles[entry.title].id) {
          visitedTitles[entry.title] = entry;
        }
      } else {
        visitedTitles[entry.title] = entry;
        titleOrder.push(entry.title);
      }
    });
    titleOrder.forEach((title) => {
      const entry = visitedTitles[title];
      if (added.indexOf(entry.id) === -1) {
        pageOrder.push(title);
        pages[title] = {
          id: entry.id,
          title: entry.title,
          content: entry.content,
          path: entry.path,
          sections: []
        };
        added.push(entry.id);
      }
    });
  }

  if (sectionResults !== undefined) {
    sectionResults.forEach((entry) => {
      if (added.indexOf(entry.id) === -1) {
        if (entry.title in pages) {
          pages[entry.title].sections.push(entry);
        } else {
          pages[entry.title] = {
            id: entry.id,
            title: entry.title,
            content: entry.content,
            path: entry.path,
            sections: []
          };
          pageOrder.push(entry.title);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  pageOrder.forEach((title) => {
    const page = pages[title];
    page.sections = filterSections(page.sections);
    results.push(pages[title]);
  });

  res.setHeader('Cache-Control', `max-age: ${maxAgeSeconds}`);
  res.status(200).json(results);
};

export default searchHandler;
```

The code is working but Typescript is complaining about `EnrichedDocumentSearchResultSetUnit`.

This has started to happen after upgrading `flexsearch` to 0.7.3.

**What am I doing wrong?**